# Self replicating neural network

Tags: c#, perl, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

Is it possible to create one neuron in a neural network and have a programme replicate the neuron and change the outputs and neuron based on input? Like a neuron evolved based on what was sent to it.

Comment: The question isn't clear... what is it about the neuron that you expect will evolve? The number of neurons in the network? The activation function?

Comment: basically: yes it is possible... please show some code... what have you tried ? what is not working ? any error messages / exceptions ?

Comment: Actually all attempts at AI has been based on "teaching" supervised, unsupervised etc. I want to try let a neural network evolve back to basics, grow as many neurons and synapses in a evolutionary approach where it evolves based on inputs and to let it grow.

Comment: its concept thinking not in practice.

Comment: then you got already three time a "yes" :-)

Comment: This question (as written) is really quite broad. If you can narrow it down a bit, I'd be happy to re-open this. Please flag for moderator attention once you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen a design like that and am not sure how it would work, but yes it's possible.  If your question is weather or not it is useful then I'm not sure.  A design would have to be implemented and tested for possible use case scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to see if it would be possible from a programming perspective.